# how to retrieve images from database and display in div using java script

Tags: javascript, sql, html

Hii,

I want to retrieve data from sql database and display dynamically in div using javascript can anyone please help me on this...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that using only javascript, as sql queries should be done using server-side technology.

First, you have to find out what kind of web hosting do you have or can afford:

1. **Web Hosting.** Usually allows you to use PHP and MySQL.
2. **Virtual Private Server, Dedicated Server.** Lets you install anything you want on the host. But, it's usually 5-10 time more expensive.

I suppose you will take simple PHP Web Hosting, as it is cheaper and more avialable.

Here you go with a detailed beginner manual on getting data from MySQL with PHP and providing it to your page: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Generally, I can't give you more information than this, as it will same as writing a book on using PHP and MySQL. So I suppose you read that link I gave you, and open separate questions if you have some other specific questions.

If, by any means, you do not want PHP, then you should search for relative documentation.

Comment: okayy thanks can you please give code snippet so that ill get some idea how to go ahead....